# Need to access the `id` of clicked `li` created inside `map` function

Tags: javascript, reactjs-flux, reactjs

I am rendering 'rows' of job listings represented by `li` elements created by calling `map` on a prop that holds an array of job listings.

Each `li` has an `onClick` handler within which I need to access the `id` associated with the clicked row in order to show the detail page of the job listing with that `id`. Note that the `map` adds the `id` values of the job listings as the `key` properties of the `li` elements.

The `map` function looks something like this:

```
var jobListRow = this.props.joblists.map(function(jobrowobj) {
  return (
    <li key={jobrowobj.id} onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <div>bla bla</div>
      <span>bla bla</span>
    </li>
  );
});
```

And the `onClick` handler looks like this:

```
handleClick: function(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
}
```

Inside the handler I hoped to use the `target` of the clicked `li` to get the value of the `key` property for that `li`, but the `target` returned seems to be different every time and happens to be a varying child element of the `li`. How can I access the `key` of the `li` that was clicked? Or, phrased differently: how can I access the `id` of the job listing that was clicked?

Comment: Are you using React Native? There's no onClick in React Native. Use onPress with TouchableHighlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, you need to have the right context binding:

```
var jobListRow = this.props.joblists.map(function(jobrowobj, i){
    return(
        <li key={jobrowobj.id} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,i)}>
            <div>bla bla</div>
            <span>bla bla</span>
        </li>
    )
});

 handleClick: function(i) {
    console.log('You clicked: ' + this.props.joblists[i]);
 }
```

Found this implementation here: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

It seems it fits your needs. Hope it helped

Comment: still does not seem to work. You can access my code through this link: https://jsfiddle.net/rosnk/sz09pmp9/1/

still getting varying child element every time i click the row. Some thing like this: 

First click:<span data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.$2.0.1.1.1">7.9 miles away</span>

second click :<h3 data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.$1.0.1.0">Job1</h3>

I dont know what is the best way to access id inside the clickhandler and would appreciate if there are other best options or solution to this.

Comment: what you want to access is not data-reactid but your key check the update

Answer (score 1):

The map function has an option to pass 'this' as a second parameter. I do it this way.

```
    var vm = this;
    var jobListRow = this.props.joblists.map(function(jobrowobj){
        return(
            <li key={jobrowobj.id} id={jobrowobj.id} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <div>bla bla</div>
                <span>bla bla</span>
            </li>
        )
    }, vm);

    handleClick: function(event) {
      console.log('You clicked: ' + event.target.id);
    }
```